# How to use integer format %00d in javascript using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use integer `%00d` in javascript using jquery.
like that integer 8 will print output like 008.

In C `printf("%00d", 8);` How about javascript?

How to solve it problem? Thanks any reply.

Comment: There's always [PHP JS's verion of `sprintf`](http://phpjs.org/functions/sprintf/) or [`printf`](http://phpjs.org/functions/printf/).

Comment: You can just do "00" + 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help.

```
('000'+8).substr(-3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a library, you should give [sprintf](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf) a try.

If not, there are several interesting options in this [question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format). Particularly, I liked this solution:

```
// First, checks if it isn't implemented yet.
if (!String.prototype.format) {
  String.prototype.format = function() {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) { 
      return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
        ? args[number]
        : match
      ;
    });
  };
}
"{0} is dead, but {1} is alive! {0} {2}".format("ASP", "ASP.NET")
```